# \newif conditional in align environment to optionally hide sub-steps in derivation

Tags: align, conditionals

I created an if true/false `\newif\ifdetail` with the hope of using this inside a `\begin{align}...\end{align}` environment.  The goal is, I'm converting my old hand-written derivations to tex, and wanted to be able to flip a macro in order to show or hide all the intermediate steps of the derivation (example, hide details in main text and put all the details in an appendix by changing the true/false declaration either in different files, or when putting the details in an appendix etc).

My attempt so far fails (below).  Does anyone have a working solution to such a set up?  The use of `align` and/or `eqnarray` are essential for multi-line equations.

When I try to get this to work inside an `align`, I can either get the false or true version to work (by wrapping the conditional with `{}` in the former case, but not both simultaneously.  It seems `align` is doing some things that conflict with this simplistic `\newif` as it causes compilation errors.  I have two minimal-working-examples (MWEs) that demonstrate these two cases.

```
% This MWE compiles 
% true:  compiles
% false: fails
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% new if true/false
\newif\ifdetail
% set it to true, this works
%\let\ifdetail\iftrue

% set it to false, this fails
\let\ifdetail\iffalse

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
a &=b 
\ifdetail
\nonumber\\&=
\textrm{intermediate step}
\fi
\nonumber\\&=
\textrm{final answer}
\end{align}


\end{document}
```

```
% This MWE compiles  - notice the extra {} surrounding the {\ifdetail...\fi}
% true:  fails
% false: compiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% new if true/false
\newif\ifdetail
% set it to true, this works
\let\ifdetail\iftrue

% set it to false, this fails
%\let\ifdetail\iffalse

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
a &=b
{\ifdetail
\nonumber\\&=
\textrm{intermediate step}
\fi}
\nonumber\\&=
\textrm{final answer}
\end{align}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have to hide the conditional code from `align` by keeping it in a group (argument), until the last minute.

So in the `align` block, I call on `\testifdetail` with the conditional code as an argument (key: in braces).  Then `\testifdetail` performs the `\if` test, but still shields the argument by invoking a call to `\testifdetailaux` only `\ifdetail` is true, and then by way of argument (again, in braces).

Finally, clear of the `align` search logic, `\testifdetailaux` is able to spit out the result directly into the `align` block.

```
% This MWE compiles 
% true:  compiles
% false: fails
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% new if true/false
\newif\ifdetail
% set it to true, this works
\detailtrue

% set it to false, this fails
%\detailfalse

\newcommand\testifdetail[1]{\ifdetail\testifdetailaux{#1}\fi}
\newcommand\testifdetailaux[1]{#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
a &=b 
\testifdetail
{\nonumber\\&=
\textrm{intermediate step}
}
\nonumber\\&=
\textrm{final answer}
\end{align}

\detailfalse

\begin{align}
a &=b 
\testifdetail
{\nonumber\\&=
\textrm{intermediate step}
}
\nonumber\\&=
\textrm{final answer}
\end{align}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm impressed how quickly you answered also :)
Tested and accepted as correct!

Comment: @walkloud Thanks, though in honesty, it took several attempts to get it to work  properly.  Welcome to the site.  You now have enough reputation to upvote.  Congratulations!

Answer (score 3):

This has something to do with where you put the line breaks. Additionally, this is not a `align` specific problem: if you do a similar version of your code using straight-up `tabular`, you get exactly the same error message. But if you move the line breaks the way I do, you are okay.

The following code works for both `\detailtrue` and `\detailfalse`; all I did is move the `\nonumber\\` around.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% new if true/false
\newif\ifdetail
\detailtrue

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
a &=b \nonumber \\
\ifdetail
&=
\textrm{intermediate step} \nonumber\\
\fi
&=
\textrm{final answer}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

---

For the benefit of smarter wizards: the same problem as reported by the OP shows up in

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifdetails
\detailstrue

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
        a & 1 
        \ifdetails
        \\ b & 2 \\
        c & 3 \\
        d & 4 
        \fi
        \\ e & 5
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

but all works well with

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifdetails
\detailsfalse

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
        a & 1 \\
        \ifdetails
        b & 2 \\
        c & 3 \\
        d & 4 \\
        \fi
        e & 5
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: TeX keeps track of the unbraced `&` tokens.

Answer (score 3):

When a conditional (`\ifdetails` in your example) starts inside the `\halign` item after first non-expadable token, then following tokens are put to the input queue until the `&` or `\cr` (in LaTeX it is `\\`) occurs. Then the input queue follows by the second part of column declaration data finalized by `\endtemplate` which is un-skippable by `\if...\fi` couple, so error arises. This is your example which can be simplify by this example:

```
\halign{x#y\cr
   a\iffalse b \cr
   c\fi \cr
}
```

The `\iffalse` here skips b but then `\cr` is replaced by the second part of column data (i.e. `y`) followed by `\endtemplate`, so we have error.

The working examples shown by Steven Segletes is based on the fact, that his conditionals start at the beginning of the template (spaces are ignored and tokens are expanded at this state, because TeX tries to find the `\omit` primitive).
The `&` and `\cr` are not replaced by the second part of column data in this state. So, they are skipable by the conditional. The example can be simplify by:

```
\halign{x#y\cr
  \iffalse b \cr
  \fi c \cr
}
```

Universal principle, how to skip a part of table data, is based on the fact, that TeX allow to read `\cr` or `&` into a macro parameter (without replacing them by second part of the column data), if it is processed at inside-braces level. This feature is implemented because TeX allows to do `\matrix{}` in `\matrix{}`, for example. It means that this works:

```
\def\ignore#1{}
\halign{x#y\cr
  a\ignore{ b \cr
  c} \cr
}
```

Your example should be solved by following code:

```
\def\ignore#1{} \def\use#1{#1}
\let\process=\ignore   %
%\let\process=\use     % select, what you want
```

and use it in your aligning macro (which is nothing other than `\halign` primitive):

```
\begin{align}
a &=b 
\process{%
   \nonumber\\&=
   \textrm{intermediate step}
}
\nonumber\\&=
\textrm{final answer}
\end{align}
```

See also TeXbook, page 248.